# Spring: Apply Annotation based on properties

Tags: spring, annotations

Say i am using @Scheduled annotation on a function. But i want that annotation to take effect only if some property is defined in properties file. How do we configure that scenario?
Use case: Same app deployed on multiple servers but @Scheduled should be active only on one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Idea:

- Use an extra bean (MyScheduler), that contains nothing more than a method annotated with @Schedule. This Method "forward" the invocation to your real Service.
- Then annotate the MyScheduler class with @Component and @Profile
- The use your properties file to enable or disable this profile

Sketch:

```
 @Component
 @Profile("onTHEserver")
 public class MyScheduler{

   @Autowire
   private RealService realService;

   @Schedule(cron="1****") {
       realService.doSomething();
   }
 }
```

- @See: [Spring 3.1 M1: Introducing @Profile](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)
- @See: [@Profile Java Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)